# Overflow: auto. Expanding past div?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the `overflow` property in CSS. Basically my problem is that instead of the content scrolling inside the div. The content expands outside the div, and makes the page scroll.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in Advance,

Curlip.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fdqrpmok/4/ Basically my code, just without all the irrelevant css.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `height` for the wrapping div

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/fdqrpmok/5/)

```html
<div style="max-width: 100px; height:150px">
  <ul style="height: 100%; overflow-y: auto; width: 100px;">
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
    <li>Blah</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="background: orange;">
  100px
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:** for 100% height wrapper [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/fdqrpmok/10/)

Comment: That was a typo... sorry

Comment: @Curlip,  it happens , just double check it :)

Comment: Another note, does the wrapper div have to be of fixed height or can it be in %. Oh and yes, I accidentally put width not height.

Comment: IT could be in `%` but it causes problems sometimes, also you need to specify `100%` for `html, body` check this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/fdqrpmok/8/

Comment: IIMO I see using [view height unit `vh`](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) much better, where `100vh` equals full view height https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/fdqrpmok/9/,  you still need to mind the padding margin etc in both cases, `

Comment: I just want it to be 100% parent height. so vh would be more confusing

Comment: but remember to reset `html` and `body` `padding:0;  margin:0; ` and give them `height:100%`